# Получить текст из PDF с помощью ItextSharp по колонкам

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itextsharp

Например, есть PDF, где текст расположен по колонкам слева направо.

Если использовать стандартный метод извлечения текста, то библиотека извлекает текст слева направо по линиям, игнорируя колонки.

Однако, если сделать в Adobe ctrl+A,ctrl+c и ctrl+v, то он копирует текст корректно по колонкам.

Можно ли подобного добиться в ItextSharp ? Может быть какие-то альтернативы, которые умеют это делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хм...

Нашел такое решение:

```
public string ReadPdfFile(string fileName)
{
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);

        for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
            string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);

            currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
            text.Append(currentText);
        }
        pdfReader.Close();
    }
    return text.ToString();
}
```